# Conditional Error Handling on MUI controls in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-hooks, conditional-statements

I want to make field mandatory on the base of condition. Here is my code snippet

```
 <Controller
            name={"InvoicingAddress.address_line_1"}
            control={control}
            rules ={{
              required: "This field is required"
            }}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value },
            }) => (
              <Input
                theme={theme}
                fullWidth={true}
                label={"Address Line 1"}
                placeholder="House number, street name"
                type="text"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={value}
                error={errors?.InvoicingAddress?.address_line_1?.message}
              ></Input>
            )}
          />
```

I want to make required on the basis of condition:
something like this:

```
{condition &&
 rules ={{
              required: "This field is required"
        }}
}
```

but the above code is not working

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I've solved something like this

```
 const [applyValidation, setApplyValidation] = useState<boolean>(false);
 function setError(): boolean {
  if(got error depending upon your condition)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

<Controller
            name={"OfficeAddress.City"}
            control={control}
            rules={{
              required: {
                value: applyValidation,
                message: ValidationMessages.CITY_REQUIRED
              }
            }}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
              <Input
                theme={theme}
                fullWidth={true}
                label={"City"}
                placeholder="e.g. company, apartment, building..."
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  onChange(e)
                  setApplyValidation(setError());
                }}
                value={value}
                error={errors?.OfficeAddress?.City?.message}

              ></Input>
            )}
          />
```